# Change favicon in DotNetNuke portal

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I'm managing several DotNetNuke portals (as well as the main hosting itself).  All of the portals have the default DNN icon in the address and when they're bookmarked.  I want to have a custom favicon.!

It's the icon on the left side of this:
[image: DNN icon]
<sub>(source: [dotnetnuke.com](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Portals/25/SystemAvatar/_thumbs/dnn_pt_xml_130x49_border.gif))</sub>

I've tried clobbering the default favicon.ico file in the root directory (where the web.config file is located).  I've deleted, I've replaced, I've restarted the browser, I've bounced IIS.  None of that works.

Has anyone come across a solution for the wonky favicon problem in DNN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to place the favicon in each portal's own folder (Portals/0/favicon.ico).  Make sure you delete the icon in the root of your website, as that will (supposedly) override any portal-specific favicons and apply to all portals.

Have a look here as well:  http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/108/threadid/183454/scope/posts/threadpage/3/Default.aspx.

Comment: That did it.  Delete the favicon in the root directory.  Then place a favicon.ico file in root/Portals/X (where X is the portal number, 0, 1, 2, whatever).

Problem solved.

Comment: the favicon in the root will not override the portal icons - it is the fall back

Comment: You shouldn't need to delete the favicon in the root.  This process has also changed in DNN 6.x.  See this post for more detail: http://www.jnrit.com.au/2012/02/25/Setting-FavIcon-for-your-DNN-Portal.aspx

Answer (score 12):

Times have changed in the DotNetNuke world since this question was answered.  Now, the favicon is much easier to change.

Go to **Site Settings** underneath the **Admin** menu, and scroll down to **Appearance**.  There should be an option to upload a new icon, or use one currently on your site.

Comment: Edited: for mobile, iphone as an example. I already config the favicon file, it working fine in desktop browsers. But doesn't display in "add bookmark windows" in Iphone? could you advise st. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Favicons are notorious for being very aggressively cached by the browser. Sometimes even clearing the cache doesn't even do the trick, it can drive you mad. Clear cache, shift-refresh etc etc...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing your browser cache?  Or try using a browser on a different machine or just a different browser (FF versus IE for isntance).  The favicon will cache and drive you crazy when it actually has changed.

The other thing to check is to see if you have more than one portal running on your DNN instance.  If you have more than one portal, you can do a different favicon for each portal by putting the favicon in portal root and not the main web root.

Comment: Make sure to fully close out your browser after clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FavIconicoCanBeABandwidthHog.aspx
Worth reading for performance purposes.